# SpriteKit overlaying audio file

Tags: sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to set a background jingle for my game which is supposed to start at the Home scene and then loop continuously even while on the other scenes.

This is what my class looks like:

```
class AudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer {
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? = AVAudioPlayer()
let ost = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bkg", ofType: "mp3")!)

func playOst() {
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ost)
        }
        catch {
            audioPlayer = nil
        }
        audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer!.play()
        audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
}

func stopOst() {
    audioPlayer!.stop()
}
```

since I put the play method in the home scene, it will start playing a new track every time I load it, overlaying one track on another making it result in a big mess. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your audio player class a singleton, or let AppDelegate look after it. This will also allow you to control the music from any scene/screen in your app at any time.

Whenever your home screen loads check to see if music is already playing, if not, call playOst, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved it with the audioPlayer.playing boolean and the singleton class